# Enable key statistics in Apache Geode Pulse

Tags: gemfire, geode

Cannot enable key-statistics (In-memory read/write and disk read/write) in Geode Pulse. I managed to import data from csv file to server region but key statistics does not change at all as shown on the attached image [screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/216Gg.png)

The region is created with `statistics-enabled` attribute.

```
<region name="workgroups" refid="REPLICATE_PERSISTENT">
    <region-attributes statistics-enabled="true">
    </region-attributes>
</region>
```

and also enable time statistics in `gemfire.properties`

```
enable-time-statistics=true
statistic-sampling-enabled=true
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you hit GEODE-2117 [1]. This was a bug introduced earlier this year in the Apache Geode Pulse code that resulted in stats of type float having a value of zero in Pulse. These values actually correspond to MBean attributes -- if you attach to the Geode Locator with JConsole you can view the same GemFire MBeans that Pulse is getting its values from. The fix was committed to the develop branch in Apache Geode and is scheduled to be in the 1.1.0 release. If you checkout the Apache Geode develop branch, build and try it again, you should see non-zero values in Pulse.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-2117

Comment: Thanks a lot. Attaching JConsole enables to see the proper result.

Comment: @dwarszawski if it looks correct in JConsole, then it's definitely GEODE-2117. You could try out the nightly build of Apache Geode which includes the bugfix. The download URL is https://builds.apache.org/job/Geode-nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/geode-assembly/build/distributions/